# Display the hashed anchor tab only on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

When I load the page each tab displays instead of the anchored tab id called in the address bar. How do I prevent all but the called anchor id from displaying on load or refresh?

```
<script>
//Grab hash off URL (default to first tab) and update
$(window).bind("hashchange", function(e) {
   var anchor = $(location.hash);
   if (anchor.length === 0) {
      anchor = $(".tabs div:eq(0)");
   }
   updateTabs(anchor);    
});

//Pass in the tab and show appropriate contents    
function updateTabs(tab) {    
   $(".tabs #tab a")    
      .removeClass("active")    
      .filter(function(index) {
            return $(this).attr("href") === '#' + tab.attr("id");    
      }).addClass("active");    
   $(".tabs .content").hide();    
   tab.show();       
}
//Fire the hashchange event when the page first loads    
$(window).trigger('hashchange');    
</script>

<div class="tabs">

    <ul>

        <li class="tab"><a href="#div1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#div2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#div3">Tab 3</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div id="div1" class="content">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="content">Div 2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="content">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine for me. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/YRjpU/1/). Is there a particular browser you're having problems with? Are you definitely including jQuery? Any errors in you Javascript console?

Comment: I used Firefox and I added $(document).ready(function() {jscode}); and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Why not hide all `.content` elements using CSS:

```
<style>
    .content { display: none; }
</style>
```

This will prevent the browser from displaying any of the `.content` elements before javascript takes over.

**Note**: If a user visits your website with javascript disabled, they will not see any of the `.content` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide all Elements with Jquery!

```
<script>
    $('.content').hide();
</script>
```

This will set Display to none for each Element, but if Javascript is disabled, the user can use everything.